# Error filtering template: Invalid block type: Wds\Coreoverride\block\Listproduct?in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I created one module and I show only product on home page customization throw .I also home page cms block call I have this error? please help me        productCollectionFactory used .

> Error filtering template: Invalid block type:
>   Wds\Coreoverride\block\Listproduct

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Check with the difference  between block class name that you provided ,or add that code what you have written for this also please modify your answer & make it little meaningful

Comment: sanni.Please post your solution as answer

Comment: spelling  mistake for block to Block then sloved.